# Cutting a section diagonally and keeping it responsive

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am looking for a way of cutting a section diagonally, kind of like the image below using CSS. It's very important that the cut stays the same on all page dimensions and doesn't overlap with the  text, while starting from the bottom left corner.

[image: [An example of the cut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6mPR.png)]

The section is a div, if it matters.

I hope you guys can help a bit

This is what I tried, but even if I change my values to fit one resolution, the moment I resize the page, it gets weird

```css
.cut
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.cut:after
 {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 65%;
    left: 0;
    height: 104%;
    width: 130%;
    background: red;
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
 }
```

Comment: Here are a couple of approaches I’ve used in the past:
https://9elements.com/blog/create-diagonal-layouts-like-it-s-2020/ (2020), https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/dppJzX/?editors=1100 (2016)

Answer (score 0):

I would use

- font size in `vw` units
- fixed `aspect-ratio`
- the cut is implemented as a `background-image`

```css
.cut {
  font-size: 3vw;
  background: cyan;
  aspect-ratio: 2/1;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3C%3Fxml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'%3F%3E%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 60 30' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M 60 20 L 60 30 L 0 30 L 60 20 Z' style='stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill: rgb(255, 0, 0); stroke-width: 0px;'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-position: bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="cut">
  One<br>
  Two<br>
  Three<br>
  Four<br>
  Five<br>
  Six<br>
  Seven<br>
  Eight<br>
  Nine<br>
  Ten<br>
  Eleven<br>
  Twelve
</div>
```

After running the snippet, make sure to click the **full page** link to properly test the responsiveness.